# dbclient - login without manually typing password

Tags: password, dropbear, chat-command

On my router which runs OpenWRT I need a script which will keep a SSH connection alive mostly all the time (small breaks are OK). As the SSH server which I want to connect to takes care of multiple connections from the same user, it is enough if I put the script to `cron` config file.

There are two problems:

- Installing stuff is not easy there (very limited space, many packages need to be compiled by me before I even try if it works).
- The server to which I want to connect does not respect RSA keys.

As my router uses [dropbear](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dbclient), I tried the following strategies:

- defining DROPBEAR_PASSWORD
- defining SSH_ASKPASS_ALWAYS and SSH_ASKPASS
- definig SSH_ASKPASS and DISPLAY
- small [chat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chat) script - no idea if it was OK, posting it below.
- `ssh login@machine < password-file &`

All in vain. To me it seems like the documentation does not apply for my `dbclient`, despite the fact that I have the latest version (Dropbear v2014.65)

Here is all what my `dbclient` can say about itself:

```
 root@OpenWrt:~# dbclient -h
 Dropbear SSH client v2014.65 (link)
 Usage: dbclient [options] [user@]host[/port] [command]
 -p <remoteport>
 -l <username>
 -t    Allocate a pty
 -T    Don't allocate a pty
 -N    Don't run a remote command
 -f    Run in background after auth
 -y    Always accept remote host key if unknown
 -y -y Don't perform any remote host key checking (caution)
 -s    Request a subsystem (use by external sftp)
 -i <identityfile>   (multiple allowed)
 -A    Enable agent auth forwarding
 -L <[listenaddress:]listenport:remotehost:remoteport> Local port forwarding
 -g    Allow remote hosts to connect to forwarded ports
 -R <[listenaddress:]listenport:remotehost:remoteport> Remote port forwarding
 -W <receive_window_buffer> (default 24576, larger may be faster, max 1MB)
 -K <keepalive>  (0 is never, default 0)
 -I <idle_timeout>  (0 is never, default 0)
 -J <proxy_program> Use program pipe rather than TCP connection
 -c <cipher list> Specify preferred ciphers ('-c help' to list options)
 -m <MAC list> Specify preferred MACs for packet verification (or '-m help')
 -V    Version
```

`chat` script:

`assword: mypassword123`

`ash` script:

```
chat -f scriptfile &
ssh login@machine
```

My router's shell is `ash`.

I read that this kind of problem is solved by `expect`, but I doubt I will have enough space on my router for it's depencencies - currently I have 300kB space left on my router, but I could somehow reclaim up to 512kB.

How do I make it connect?

Comment: The point of expect is not to fake detaching from a terminal, but to provide a terminal where there isn't one, which is exactly what you need here. Compiling isn't a big deal (minutes to install the compiler, seconds for the actual compilation), and you can probably get a binary anyway, but the space requirement may be an issue (expect comes with a TCL interpreter, which is pretty big).